# AS3 dividing integers

Tags: actionscript-3

This is just a simple problem, i have two integers (for example)

```
var myInt:int = 3357;
var myOtherInt:int = 10;
```

Then i ask flash to trace myInt divided by myOtherInt

```
trace(myInt / myOtherInt);
```

And in the output menu i get 335.7 as the traced number and i need to get an integer which would be 335.

Comment: try with something like, trace(int(myInt / myNumber));

Comment: I'm glad it helped, basically you needed to also specify the calculation to be an integer. In other workds the int() will cast to an integer the inner calculation value.

Comment: @Eric Fortis: perhaps you want to place your comment as an answer instead, so Noah Katz can close the thread?

Answer (score 7):

Try with something like:

```
trace(int(myInt / myNumber));
```

You need to type cast the division to integer, this will trunk the decimal part.

Alternatively you can use `Math.round(335.7)` -> `336` or `Math.floor(335.7)` -> `335`

Comment: Also, if you intend to assign the result to an int type variable, an implicit conversion is done and you don't need the cast. If you're already doing this, you might have the correct code already and only your trace output is misleading.